# Azure, internet facing load balancer without using cloud services

Tags: load-balancing, azure, ansible

Is it possible to have load balancing between virtual machines without placing the machines in the same cloud service?

We want to use Ansible to configure our machines and setup RabbitMQ but I can't see how it could be done without having an public IP to each of the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The azure VM while not having a public IP can be accessed via SSH using a specific port. In your ansible inventory file you can define the ansible_host and ansible_port for each of your VM's.

```
[all]
test01vm0 ansible_host=test01.europe.cloudapp.azure.com ansible_port=50000
test01vm1 ansible_host=test01.europe.cloudapp.azure.com ansible_port=50001
```

Comment: This is the solution we ended up using, forgot to post the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Traffic Manager to balance requests between different cloud services at DNS level http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/

I don't know if it fits RabbitMQ needs.